# Using Crypto.RSA.generate() with your own randfunc

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I have created my own random number generator and I am trying to use it in `RSA.generate()` functions as `randfunc` parameter. My generator returns txt file of bits and I would like to read it as randfunc with `file.read` however I get a `Index out of range` error. I know that when you put an image it works but I don't know how to make txt file work or any other data structure like list or array work.

Error code:

```
msb = bord(randfunc(1)[0])
IndexError: index out of range
```

File:

```
filePath = "data.txt"
file = open(file,'rb')
```

Generating bits:

```
outputFile = open(outputFile_path, 'a')
bufor += str(int(math operations)) 

if(bitCounter > 7):
    outputFile.write(bufor)
    bufor = ''
    byteCounter += 1
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code you are asking about.

Comment: I have code with my generator which is long, but it just generates file with 0s and 1s (as characters) but it can be simply turned into binary file with 8-bit integers. There's not really any more code than `private_key = RSA.generate(1024,file.read)`

Comment: What about the code that defines `file`?  What about the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Sorry, now I provided those informations

Comment: You have to show your `randfunc` code since that must be where the problem is.

Comment: Edited the post to show the most important part of saving values in the generator. I was wandering whether saving data as binary would help